# Column value as column alias in a survey results query

Tags: sql-server

I am facing a problem in building a query of the following scenario. I am listing tables and values for an example:

### Responses Table

```
╔═════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ QID ║ Response_ID ║ Response_Title ║ Answer_Col_Label ║ Answer_Col_Value ║
╠═════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  10 ║         500 ║ Blue           ║ Q10_isBlue       ║                1 ║
║  10 ║         501 ║ Green          ║ Q10_isGreen      ║                2 ║
║  10 ║         502 ║ Yellow         ║ Q10_isYellow     ║                3 ║
╚═════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Then in results table, values are as under:

### Results Table

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║ Q_ID ║ answers ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║   10 ║     502 ║
╚══════╩═════════╝
```

In results table, there is response_id pushed in answers column, which means that user selected this response_id from radio button/checkbox.

Now I want to create a query where I want to show answer_col_label value (Lable_a) in column heading for including all responses of responses table and showing answer_value as selected result under that column heading.

Please help me creating this query in SQL Server. Thank you for time and help.

### Edit - Required Query Result

Here is format of query result, I want to achieve:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Q10_isBlue ║ Q10_isGreen ║ Q10_isYellow ║
╠════════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ NULL       ║ Null        ║            3 ║
╚════════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Where Q10_isYellow = 3 is the value of response_id = 502 in responses table. The result table will join with responses table to get its column label and column value which in this case is, ***"Q10_isYellow"*** and ***"3"*** respectively.

Hope this edit section will improve my question further to understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: As posted your question is not clear what you are trying to do. And which DBMS are you using sql-server or postgre? You need to provide some details about the tables involved and the desired result. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have updated my question with EDIT. I am using MS SQL Server 2014. Hopefully now you can understand the problem.

Comment: Nope I don't understand your data at all. You have ResponseID = 500 but somehow that becomes 502 as an answer. There are some details missing here to allow me to understand your data.

Comment: Ok. Let me expain. Question is ***"Which is your favorite color?"*** and there are three possible responses ***"500 - Blue"***, ***"501 - Green"***, ***"502 - Yellow"***. Now these responses are presented with Radio buttons. User selected ***"Yellow"*** and ***502*** is recorded in result table which is the ID of Yellow color. Now I need to place column labels of each response id as column headings and put the selected one with the code given in answer_col_value in case of selected option.

Comment: OK with your last edit the values make sense now thanks. Do you need to pivot all possible answers? That seems kind of silly. There can only 1 value filled in right so why do you need empty columns? Why not return QID, ResponseTitle. The only thing I can think of is you need this to be dynamic and pivoted. This means you will need a dynamic pivot or dynamic crosstab. I would use the Responses table and then left join the Results. And with your dynamic code you will have to build the column names.

Comment: Yes these values will be pivoted or Case/When stement can be built, but these empty columns are needed. It is analysis requirement to see all options presented and only selected one will have designated code below them. I will grateful if you can quote your answer to help me out figuring it out.

Comment: Also there is one record for example purpose, there are thousands of such records. But needed to have one row per respondent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using a dynamic cross tab.

First we need tables and data to work with.

```
create table #Responses
(
    QID int
    , ResponseID int
    , ResponseTitle varchar(50)
    , AnswerColLabel varchar(50)
    , AnswerColValue int
)

insert #Responses
select 10, 500, 'Blue', 'Q10_isBlue', 1 union all
select 10, 501, 'Green', 'Q10_isGreen', 2 union all
select 10, 502, 'Yellow', 'Q10_isYellow', 3

create table #Results
(
    QID int
    , answers int
)

insert #Results
select 10, 502
```

I also use a tally table here. I keep this in a view on my system so I don't have to write it over and over.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now that the problem is setup we can look at some code. This technique is known as dynamic cross tabs. Jeff Moden has a great article about it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 'with OrderedResults as
    (
        select r.*, ru.answers, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by r.QID order by ResponseID) as RowNum
        from #Responses r
        left join #Results ru on ru.QID = r.QID and ru.answers = r.ResponseID
    )
    select r.QID '



declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
' from OrderedResults r 
group by r.QID'

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion +
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(t.N as varchar(6)) + ' then case when r.answers is not null then r.AnswerColValue end end) as ' + r.AnswerColLabel
from #Responses r
left join #Results ru on ru.QID = r.QID and ru.answers = r.ResponseID
join cteTally t on t.N = r.AnswerColValue

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + @DynamicPortion + @FinalStaticPortion;
--select @SqlToExecute
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

Comment: Thank you for response Lange. But the result query showing 502 rather than showing 3 for Yellow.

Comment: Try now. I am a little bit concerned that you couldn't figure out that out. It demonstrates you don't understand what this code is doing because the fix was pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was digesting your solution. Trying few attempts in my own language :P. I got it managed later on. I was actually translating your response into my actual table structures, and I got that by replacing sub-query table and replacing CTE part.

Comment: The change is inside the string of @DynamicPortion. You can click on the edited link at the bottom of my answer and see the revisions highlighted which will show you nicely that changes. :)

Comment: Yes I got that. Thank you very much Lange for your time & quick help. Very nice and quick response. I was anticipating it by using case/when but was not reaching the dynamic part which you suggested in your answer. That made my problem resolved.

Comment: How can vote you up? Sorry I m new to SO and first time I posted something here.

Comment: Cool glad that worked for you. Make sure you understand that code. It is not basic sql there. And if something goes wrong in production it is your phone they will be calling. Feel free to ask for clarification on any parts of it you don't understand and I will be happy to explain it.

Comment: Sure I will. So nice of you. Thanks again.